# checking a function was called or not

Tags: c++, function, c++11

Let's say I have following code:

```
// I'll be providing these 3
int a = 0;
void setA(){ a = 1000;}
void processA() { std::cout << a; }

// User will call them
int main(){
    // setA();    // <-- Notify about this
    processA();
    return 0;
}
```

Here I must make sure that someone has called `setA()` before calling `processA()`. I've thought about 2 ways to do this:

- call `setA()` just inside `processA()` function or just dump the contents of `setA()` inside `processA()`
- maintain a boolean flag and check at later state to make sure `setA()` has been called

Now 1st method makes sense but the problem is `setA()` function would be called a lot earlier than `processA()` and I just cannot do this. 2nd way is fine but is runtime dependent.

Is there a way to make this work in compile time, so that there is a message/warning or a compiler warning would be the best way to alert user that he/she hasn't called `setA()` before processing it.

Comment: @KerrekSB which question? I've not asked this question before.

Comment: Some kind of "once" flag seems appropriate. You can set it unconditionally in `setA()`, and `processA()` can check the flag and conditionally call `setA()`. Or you could literally use [`std::call_once`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once).

Comment: Create a `class A` which initializes its members in the constructor. Then call `process` on that object.

Comment: You don't mention how long it takes but you could look to some form of static initialisation as well, or if expensive, [Howard has this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31467839/3747990) as well.

Comment: use a pure virtual function instead make `setA` as base method

Comment: Sure, you need to wrap `setA` in a class.

Comment: A similar question has been asked here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588622/forbid-code-to-compile-if-some-function-is-not-called/35588778#35588778]. For the compile time question, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are looking for encapsulation. Just write a class that makes it impossible for the user to forget calling `setA()`:

```
class Foo {
    public:
        Foo() { setA(); }
        process() { /*...*/ }
    private:
        void setA() { /*...*/ }
        int a;
};
```

Comment: Hmm this could do, now I've to test whether constructor would still be called if I declared the constructor private to use process as static methods.

Comment: well... this would be a different question, and no, if you make the destructor private you cannot create objects of that class (well you can but the short answer is: no you cant). static methods dont require an object, thus calling a static methods dont care at all about the constructor

Comment: ...but why static methods?